# printf command printing 2 parameter in one line

Tags: awk

How can we use `printf` to show this below output with percentage sign

```
used1=64.1
printf "USED =%.1f\n", used1 " %"
```

Require output

```
output is USED=64.1%
```

Below is the actual script with awk

```
isi storagepool list -v |awk 'function num2gb(n) { if (n ~ /T$/) return n / 1; return n / 1024; }
    /Requested Protection:/ { parity=substr($NF,length($NF)-1,1) }
    /Nodes:/ { nodes=$NF }
    /HDD Total/ { hdd_total=$NF }
    /HDD Used/ { hdd_used=num2gb($NF) }
    END {
        multiplier=nodes-parity
        total=hdd_total/nodes*multiplier
        used=hdd_used/nodes
        eu=used*multiplier*0.8
        et=total*0.8
        used1=eu/et*100
        print "parity =" parity
        print "NodeNumber =" nodes
        printf ("Total =%.1f\n", total, TB);
        printf "Effective Total volume =%.1f\n", total*0.8, " TB"
        printf "USED =%.1f\n", used1 " %"
        printf "Effective used=%.1f\n", used*multiplier*0.8, " TB"
        printf "Available volume=%.1f\n", (hdd_totalhdd_used)/nodes*multiplier*0.8, " TB"
        printf "HDD Total=%.1f\n", hdd_total}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` for `printf` is special character which defines print formatting, you need to escape it with another `%` in `printf` if you want literal `%` in output and better move it inside first control area. see [man printf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf)

```
printf("USED =%.1f %%\n", used1)
```

Or you can single quote it as below.

```
printf("USED =%.1f '%'\n", used1)
```

Or you can print that as **c**haracter using `%c`.

```
printf("USED =%.1f %c\n", used1, "%")
```

Or its ASCII code instead.

```
printf("USED =%.1f %c\n", used1, 37)
```

Comment: you gave me many options, I will surly test them all, but now `%%`  is working.

Comment: this `printf("USED =%.1f '%'\n", used1)` one or even this one `printf("USED =%.1f %\n", used1)` also works in `awk` but I don't suggest to use these, better use `%%` compatibility option or with `%c` or ASCII mode with their relevant control formatting